# Can I perform Puja in home during menstruation of anyone in my home?

Tags: shiva, women, puja

I would like to know whether I can perform Puja to Lord Shiva during menstruation period of my sister in my home?

I think, she cannot perform Puja but what about myself being a male member in her family?

Comment: As long as the menstruating lady is not involved in the puja and is not in contact with puja dravyas and puja sthalam you can perform puja at home.

Comment: Additionally, the lady must isolate herself and must not come in contact with anything that you will be handling- food, water, clothes etc.  She must also not watch the puja.

Answer (score -1):

As long as puja is done without any material expectations it can be done at any time and place when the mind is ready for it ☺
The physical conditions of other people at home should be immaterial. On the other hand, it may not be acceptable to other people if your sister prepares offerings which are then distributed to people. But the divine should not have a problem with it.

As per the Upanishads,

> Sarvam khalvidam brahma

which includes your sister.

Comment: To delete your answer, simply press delete button instead of edit button.

Comment: I do not see the delete option. Hence the edit.

Comment: @DroidSK Under your answer, there are 4 options. Share, edit, delete, flag. Click on delte. Are you using mobile web or desktop site?